# Polygamma function approximation to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, polygamma

Be $\psi_0(s)$ the polygamma function of order zero in $s \in C$. Do you think is correct to write
$
\psi_{0}(s) + \psi_{0}(-s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{-s+n} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{s+n} = lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \psi_0(-s + n + 1) + \psi_0,(s + n + 1) -\psi_0 (1 - s) - \psi_0(s + 1)  =  -\psi_0 (1 - s) - \psi_0(s + 1)$

where partial sum is given by mathwolfram site
rappresenting $\psi(s),\psi(-s)$ as series
$\sum_{m=1}^n(1/(-s + m) + 1/(s + m)) = \Psi_0(-s + n + 1) + \Psi_0,(s + n + 1) -\Psi_0 (1 - s) - \Psi_0(s + 1) $

Comment: I don't get why $$\psi ^{(0)}(n-s+1)+\psi ^{(0)}(n+s+1)-\psi ^{(0)}(s+1)-\psi ^{(0)}(1-s)$$ becomes $$-\psi ^{(0)}(s+1)-\psi ^{(0)}(1-s)$$

Comment: Because first two term espressed as series goes zero when denominator goes infinity

Comment: My calculations show a different scenario. Plugging $n = 100, s = 0.5$ LHS gives $11.1$ while RHS gives $1.9$

Comment: Yes, it is valid only when n goes infinity

Comment: Not really $$\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(\psi ^{(0)}(n-s+1)+\psi ^{(0)}(n+s+1)-\psi ^{(0)}(s+1)-\psi ^{(0)}(1-s)\right)=\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

The correct approximation  as $n\to\infty$ is
$$\sum _{k=1}^{n } \frac{1}{k-s}+\sum _{k=1}^{n } \frac{1}{k+s}\sim \frac{1}{n}+2 \log n -\psi ^{(0)}(s+1)-\psi ^{(0)}(1-s)$$

Comment: Taylor expansion at $n=\infty$ of $\psi ^{(0)}(n-s+1)+\psi ^{(0)}(n+s+1)-\psi ^{(0)}(1-s)-\psi ^{(0)}(s+1)$. Set $n=1/x$ and get MaxLaurin expansion $-\psi ^{(0)}(1-s)-\psi ^{(0)}(s+1)+x-2 \log (x)$, then plug back $x=1/n$